# Programmatic access to Azure AD SSO enabled SaaS app data

Tags: javascript, azure

I have enabled SSO using Azure Premium AD with Google Apps, i can login to Google apps when I go to browser and click my apps however I need to get data programmatic after I login into O365. Instead of clicking my apps i need to use a programmatic snippets (ex., javascript) query some data from google apps or any configured SaaS based apps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [adal for js](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js) to authenticate and authorize your users. You can write a initialization functionality in your client application using javascript. When the document is loaded, check whether the user is signed in, if so, call your additional APIs, if not, use adal to login.